# How do I get ajax into a jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have some working code that using ajax to rewrite some html when various links are clicked. What I would like it to do instead is to create a dialog box on the fly on a hover event rather than rewriting some html on the fly on a click event. Here is the working click code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/spacious/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <body>


<div id="book001">
  <a href="javascript:{}" class="citation"><span class="book">I, Robot</span><br>
  <div id="author001"></div>
</div>
<div id="book002">
  <a href="javascript:{}" class="citation"><span class="book">Stranger In A Strange Land</span><br>
  <div id="author002"></div>
</div>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

  $j( ".citation" ).click(function ( )
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var get_book = $j(this).find('span.book').html();
    var divName = $j(this).parent().attr('id');
    $j.ajax({                                      
      url: 'book_api.php',       
      data: {
        book:get_book,
      },
      dataType: 'json',    
      success: function(data)
      {
        var content = data[4];
        $j('#'+divName.replace('book','output')).html(content);
      } 
    });
  }); 

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I intend to use jQuery UI to create the dialog. I am a bit fuzzy on how to get the ajax code to influence the dialog content. The page will have hundreds of such links on it so I don't want to prepopulate hundreds of dialog boxes.

Comment: How much data is returned by book_api.php? or Data to be displayed is much or only a few lines? Maybe yo could use jquery ui tooltip or similar. Or definitively you have to use a dialog?

Comment: It is just a few lines so a tooltip could be fine but I would still have the same problem of not wanting the weight of every tooltip being prepopulated. There will be hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer is quite simple. Just replace the repeating divs for each author like:

```
<div id="author002"></div>
```

with a single div that is the container for the dialog box:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

and then just reference `$j( "#dialog" ).html` rather than `$j('#'+divName.replace('book','output')).html`.

Answer (score 0):

A user can fire many hover events quickly, so binding an ajax call to each of them might not be your best strategy.  In production, your list will be populated from a database, so if you fetch your desired information (assuming this is a small bit of json) along with the list of titles, you can construct your html such that the json sits in a data attribute in the anchor tag.  Then you can use jQuery to populate your tooltip without any delays or additional calls.

```
<a data-info="<some data about this book>">I, Robot</a>

$j(".citation").hover(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($j(this).data('info'));
});
```

Comment: There is a way to stall a hover event, right? I mean only fire the event if they hover for 2 seconds or something like that.

Comment: I am not worried about delays or additional calls, I am worried about a long load time for the page when most of the tooltip data is unneeded.

Comment: You can try a plugin like [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) and that might be all you need!

Comment: While hoverintent is pretty slick, no one seems to be keying in on the question. What I am asking about is how to dynamically create the content on the event, not how to change "click" to "hover".